# Fill Image with its content in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

I am creating a Widget in SwiftUI and I'm finding what I believe is a very silly issue.

I have an `Image` that I want to use as a background. I have set its aspect ratio as `.fill` but it doesn't seem to do it.

Here's the code:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(affirmation.customImageName ?? "c_0")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.green)
            
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text(affirmation.title)
                        .font(.title)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
            
        }
    }
```

And how it looks:
[image]

Also, if I delete `.frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)`, the image won't use the whole area.

**UPDATED**:

Now the image resizes thanks to @staticVoidMan answer, adding `resizable()` did the trick. The issue now is that the `Text` seems to also resize and fill more than its space.

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           Image(affirmation.customImageName ?? "c_0")
           .resizable()
           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            
            HStack {
                Text(affirmation.title)
                    .font(.body)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
            
        }
```

Here's the image:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @staticVoidMan I get `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'resizable'` am I missing something?

Comment: try `.resizable()` just after `Image` before `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`

Comment: wow, what kind of dark magic is that :O ! It worked 100%, thank you a lot

Comment: hah. yup. that's `Image` for you in `SwiftUI`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @staticVoidMan... but now my Text also resizes?

Comment: nope. `resizable` is a view modifier for `Image` only

Comment: update your question and lets see if we find some elegant solution. cant really see your text problem in the question right now.

Comment: @staticVoidMan edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `.resizable` is an `Image` view modifier that allows it to occupy the maximum amount of space required.
2. `ZStack` by default can stretch indefinitely to fit all it's inner views and hence you need to define the frame via the `.frame` modifier so all the inner views stay within defined limits.

i.e.

```
ZStack {
    //...
}
.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
```

---

### Solution:

```
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Image("yourImageName")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .background(Color.green)
    
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor set amet")
        .font(.title)
        .padding(.leading, 5)
}
.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
```

- `ZStack(alignment: .leading)` reduces the need of `HStack:Text|Spacer` to just the `Text`
- `.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)` is default so not required
- `.lineLimit(nil)` is default so not required

Answer (score 1):

1. code

```
V/Hstack({}).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(
            Image("yourImageName")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        )
```

2. check your image resolution.I came into the image resolution problem. The image with resolution value **72x72** cannot fulfill the Widget background. Use the image with **144x144** resolution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I manage to cover the full widget background space after adopting the latest:

```
.containerBackground(for: .widget) {
}
```

Extra info here:
https://swiftsenpai.com/development/widget-container-background/